# Why the first variable of the affine conncetion only depends on the value at a point?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

On a Riemannian manifold $M,$ for any smooth tangent vector field $X,Y,Z,$ if $X(p)=Y(p),$ then any affine connection satisfies that
$$
\nabla_XZ(p)=\nabla_YZ(p).
$$
Why this happens? I know the key point should be the $C^\infty$-linear property,
$$
\nabla_{fX}Z=f\nabla_XZ,\quad f\in C^\infty(M).
$$
However I don't know how to use it. It turns that we only need to show if $X(p)=0,$ then $\nabla_XZ(p)=0.$

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify what is assumed, and what exactly is asked, i.e., is to be shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know at least how to prove that the connection is local, i.e $\nabla_XY$ depends only on the values of $X$ and $Y$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, then you can write in a local frame $X=X^iE_i$ such that $X^i(p)=0$, then as you said :
$$\nabla_XZ=X^i\nabla_{E_i}Z$$

So evaluating in $p$ :
$$\nabla_XZ|_p=X^i(p)\nabla_{E_i}Z|_p=0$$

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use $\nabla_XZ=f\nabla_{X/f}Z$ at first, where $f(p)=0.$ But I'm not sure how to choose $f$ properly to make $X/f$ well defined. It's really interesting that I can get the conclusion by decomposing it.

Comment: You can see it from a different angle if you're familiar with tensors. If we fix $Y$, then the application $T:\mathfrak{X}(M)\rightarrow\mathfrak{X}(M):X\mapsto\nabla_XY$ is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear by hypothesis in X, so it is a (1,1)-tensor on M. And as you probably know, tensors in general depend only on the value of their arguements in a given point.